# JGit How get list of RevCommit for DiffEntry

Tags: java, git, git-diff, jgit

I get difference between two branches using JGit as follows:

```java
ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();

CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();

Ref master = git.getRepository().exactRef(getRefBranchName( branchMaster) );
RevTree masterTree = new RevWalk(git.getRepository()).parseTree(master.getObjectId());
    oldTreeIter.reset(reader, masterTree.getId());

Ref release = git.getRepository().exactRef(getRefBranchName( branchRelease));
RevTree releaseTree = new RevWalk(git.getRepository()).parseTree(release.getObjectId());
    newTreeIter.reset(reader, releaseTree.getId());

List<DiffEntry> diffs = git.diff().setNewTree(newTreeIter).setOldTree(oldTreeIter).call();
```

Then I can print differences in files as follows:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter (outputStream);
formatter.setRepository(git.getRepository());
for (DiffEntry entry: diffs){               
    System.out.println("Diff Entry: " + entry + ", from: " + entry.getOldId()+", to: " + entry.getNewId());
    formatter.format(entry);
    String diffText = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(diffText);
    outputStream.reset();
}
```

I saw all differences between two files in this branches, but how can I get all commits for this differences for certain `DiffEntry`? I have not found a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DiffEntry` does not have 'a list of `RevCommit`s'. It represents a single change to a file and describes whether a file was added, modified, or deleted. And a commit must not necessarily be the source of the change.

However, you already have pointers to the commits that the DiffEntries are computed from. It's `master` and `release`.

With `ref.getObjectId()` you can obtain the id of the commit that the ref currently points to.

To obtain a `RevCommit` that contains all metadata of the commits and points to its *tree*, you need to use a `RevWalk` like this:

```java
try( RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repository ) ) {
  RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit( master.getObjectId() );
}
```

For more about JGit's diff API you may want to read thje article [What’s the Difference? Creating Diffs with JGit](http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/06/16/jgit-diff/)